# Running webgl JS file from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to learn JavaScript by learning WebGL, which should be a semi-contained environment. I am trying to figure out how to run the code below, either from the command line or in a browser. I was able to require the THREE.js libraries, but it doesn't look like I can require the document object as easily. Perhaps I need to get a JavaScript shell? How can I get Mozilla or another browser to run the .js code below? I have the following code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*global THREE, Coordinates, $, document, window*/


//var document = require('document');
var THREE = require('three');
var camera, scene, renderer;
var windowScale;
var cameraControls;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

function drawGoldCube() {

    var cube;
    var cubeSizeLength = 100;
    var goldColor = "#FFDF00";
    var showFrame = true;
    var wireMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: goldColor, wireframe: showFrame } ) ;

    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cubeSizeLength, cubeSizeLength, cubeSizeLength);

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, wireMaterial );
    cube.position.x = 0;    // centered at origin
    cube.position.y = 0;    // centered at origin
    cube.position.z = 0;    // centered at origin
    scene.add( cube );

}

function init() {
    var canvasWidth = 846;
    var canvasHeight = 494;
    // For grading the window is fixed in size; here's general code:
    //var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
    //var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var canvasRatio = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x808080, 2000, 4000 );
    // LIGHTS
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

    // RENDERER
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.gammaInput = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    // CAMERA
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, canvasRatio, 1, 4000 );
    camera.position.set( -200, 200, -150 );
    // CONTROLS
    cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitAndPanControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    cameraControls.target.set(0,0,0);

    // draw the coordinate grid
    Coordinates.drawGrid({size:1000,scale:0.01});
    Coordinates.drawGrid({size:1000,scale:0.01, orientation:"y"});
    //Coordinates.drawGrid(size:1000,scale:0.01, orientation:"y"});
    Coordinates.drawGrid({size:1000,scale:0.01, orientation:"z"});
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    cameraControls.update(delta);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
drawGoldCube();
animate();
```

it's failing at the document.getElementById() line.

My question is - can I run this outside a browser?
If I am at the command line, can I run "node my_webgl.js"? I was able to install THREE.js but I am not sure if I can require a "document" variable.
So this line at the top "var document = require('document');" is failing if I uncomment it.

How can I run this code? Preferably from the command line. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get this code from?

Comment: Udacity.com course, it runs in the cloud, trying to figure out how to run it on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Working with THREE.js requires you to be in an actual browser window that has WebGL support ( or canvas support if you're going to use the fallback ).

Comment: so maybe there is a command line option to run my JS file....maybe like >mozilla three.js ? why can't I do that? when I do that, it just opens the JS file to view in a browser, but it doesn't run the code...

Comment: Browsers have to render documents - so at the very least, you could create a file called three.html that has the expected DOM structure along with a <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js"></script> tag.  You could then run "google-chrome three.html" or "firefox three.html" - etc. etc.